# RecyclerView using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not displaying data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Android studio.I'm using firestore recyclerview adapter to display list a of leagues after a user signs in; however, the recyclerview of Leaguelist activity isn't showing any items. It only shows the list of leagues when I try to add another league using floatingActionButton(still using the same activity). Then if I move on to the next activity then go back to the Leaguelist activity, I don't see any of league items unless I try to add another league again.

```
public class LeagueListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LeagueRecycleAdapter.OnItemClickListener{



    List<League> leagueList;
    LeaguesRepository leaguesRepository = new LeaguesRepository();
    ListView listView;
    LeagueAdapter adapter;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    static final int GET_LEAGUE_NAME = 1;
    FloatingActionButton btnAddLeague;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CollectionReference leagueRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("myLeague");
    private LeagueRecycleAdapter leagueRecycleAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_league_recycleview);

        coordinatorLayout=findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout_leagues);
           setUpRecycleView();

         btnAddLeague =findViewById(R.id.floatingButton_add_league);
         btnAddLeague.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startActivityForResult(new Intent
                         (LeagueListActivity.this,
                                 EditNameActivity.class), GET_LEAGUE_NAME);
             }
         });
         // hide the title of this activity
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


             }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == GET_LEAGUE_NAME) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                 if(data.getStringExtra("SAVE").isEmpty()){
                     Toast.makeText(
                             this, "You didn't add a league", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }else{
                     leaguesRepository.addLeague(data.getStringExtra("SAVE"));
                 }




            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
                Toast.makeText(
                        this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add:
                                startActivityForResult(new Intent
                        (LeagueListActivity.this,
                                EditNameActivity.class), GET_LEAGUE_NAME);

                return true;

]
            case R.id.action_logout:
                ]
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:
                logoutUser();

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }

    private void logoutUser() {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(LeagueListActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
       private void setUpRecycleView(){
        Query query=leagueRef;
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<League> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<League>()
                .setQuery(query,League.class).build();
        leagueRecycleAdapter=new LeagueRecycleAdapter(options);

         recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_league);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(leagueRecycleAdapter);

        leagueRecycleAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new LeagueRecycleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                String id=documentSnapshot.getId();
                League league = new League();
                league.setDocumentId(id);
                Intent intent = new Intent(LeagueListActivity.this, NamingTeamsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", id);
               startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        leagueRecycleAdapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        leagueRecycleAdapter.stopListening();
    }


    }




[LeaguelistActivity][1]
[adding a league][2][recycleview is populated][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EQN1.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5egzo.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii87c.png
```

Comment: Have you tried to comment `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing happened though unless I try to add another league item